# OAuth 2.0 PHP регистрация пользователей

Tags: php, oauth2

Читая документацию по Oauth2 server php, не уловил один момент, возможно я не так понял но библиотека подразумевает авторизацию. Пользователь уже есть в базе, у него есть client_secret, client_id и тд, а как реализовать авторизацию? Если пользователь первый раз заходит в андройд приложение, и вводит пароль и логин, как все это правильно генерировать и заносить в базу, проверять на уникальность и так далее. Возможно не корректно задал вопрос но буду благодарен за любое разъяснение.

Comment: В базу заносить стандартно, генерировать стандартно..проверять, например, через сессии (токен, айди и т.п.)..Если юзер в базе существует, то просто обновляем токен.. Обычно так делается для vk api.. Может кто то делает по другому